# I need help calculating tent pole length for my lost poles.

Tags: geometry

I lost the two fiberglass shock corded tent poles to my small dome tent. The tent base is 7'X 7' and the two poles insert in external sleeves that extend across the top to opposite corners, crossing each other at the top. I estimate the inside clearance height inside the middle of the tent to be about 54 inches (4.5 feet). So the poles would have to create an arc a little higher than that because the tent hangs below the supporting poles.
I can order replacement poles, but don't know what their length should be. I'm guessing around 14-14.5 feet, but I could be way off.
Thanks for any help.
Frank.

Comment: This is a case where the math doesn't really fit the reality because the tent isn't a perfect half sphere and what we assume won't necessarily be what the tent makers assum  But assuming the tent is a half sphere and the cross arc cross symmtrecall in the center, then you have a half circle with radius 54.  so the pole should be $54\pi$ or $14$ feet.  But I imagine it will be a little less.  The you have the tent model number.  I'd call the tent makers.

Comment: The diagonal of the tent is just under 10 feet in length. A half circle with this diameter would have the poles about 15' 9" with center height a little less than 5 feet due to suspension. If the actual height was only 4' 6", then the poles were likely about 15' 6".